# Why do I get E11000 duplicate key error with MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

this C# application needs to work with a MongoDB. When I try to add data, I get the error: E11000 duplicate key error collection: aap.Olas index: *id* dup key: { : BinData(3, 00000000000000000000000000000000) }

This is the code that adds Data to the DB

```
public void Add(IDataType item,string name)
{
     IMongoCollection<IDataType> collection = db.GetCollection<IDataType>(name);
     collection.InsertOne(item);
}
```

This is what the interface looks like.

```
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using System;

namespace Labo04.GLOBAL
{
    public interface IDataType
    {
        [BsonId]
        Guid Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the class Ola, the data I try to insert.

```
public class OLA : IDataType
    {
        [BsonId]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Naam { get; set; }
        public int Studiepunten { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Docent> Docenten { get; set; }
        public virtual OPO Opo { get; set; }

        public OLA()
        {
        }

        public OLA(string code, string naam, int studiepunten, List<Docent> docenten, OPO opo)
        {
            this.Code = code;
            this.Naam = naam;
            this.Studiepunten = studiepunten;
            this.Docenten = docenten;
            this.Opo = opo;
        }
    }
```

How can I fix this.

Comment: There already exists a document with value of id say x and you're trying to insert another record with a value of id=x

Comment: I know but The Id's should be auto generated.

Comment: The type of Id is Guide in your class, to generate it automatically it should be ObjectId.

Comment: I changed it to auto ObjectID but still nothing

Comment: I think you are trying to add a document which already exists and the unique index is blocking it, check your indexes using [`getIndexes`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.getIndexes/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem. It is because you are generating the `Collection` from `IDataType`:

```
db.GetCollection<IDataType>(name);
```

`IDataType` should be the final class object, so instead of passing the interface instance to this function, you can use generics:

```
public void Add<DataType>(DataType item,string name)
{
     IMongoCollection<DataType> collection = db.GetCollection<DataType>(name);
     collection.InsertOne(item);
}
```